# How to convert array of string to object?

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, functional-programming

I have got a object of arrays property . For getting accepted output , I made two 
   methods in code.

Method 1: is going  to show array of objects instead of array of string value inside object.
 Method 2: is going  to show my accpeted output.

```
let data = {
  Invoice: ["can_view", "can_create", "can_edit", "can_delete"],
  license: ["can_view", "can_create", "can_edit", "can_delete"] 
}
```

the problem is that I doing an extra loop inside method 1 for getting array of objects. then it converted to method for accepting data

I don't need Method 1 , I want to getting my accepted data based array of string.

what should be changed inside method 2 ?

// Method 1 :

```
 let values = Object.entries(data).map(([key, values]) => ({
      [key]: values.map(v => ({ label: v, value: v }))
    }));
console.log(values)
```

// Method:2

```
 function convertdatatoObj (value,group){
   let permissionAccess;
    let permissionArray = value && value.filter(item => item[group]);
    const permissionObj = Object.assign({}, permissionArray);
    let res =
      permissionObj[0] &&
      permissionObj[0][group] &&
      permissionObj[0][group].map(item => {
        return {
          value: item.value
        };
      });
    const obj = Object.assign({}, res);
    permissionAccess = Object.fromEntries(
      Object.entries(obj) && Object.entries(obj).map(([k, v]) => [v.value, v])
    );
    return permissionAccess;

 }

 let result = convertdatatoObj(values,"Invoice")

console.log(result) 

// My accepeted Output would be this format:

let res = {
can_view: {value: "can_view"},
can_create: {value: "can_create"},
can_edit: {value: "can_edit"},
can_delete: {value: "can_delete"},
}
```

Comment: So, is `value` in Method2 supposed to use the `data` from the beginning?

Comment: yes , now , I am passing data from method 1 , but now , it should be data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have the object and the name, you can just get the corresponding array and transform it using [`Array#map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) into the key, which is the given array entry, and the value which is `{value: <item entry>}`. Finally, construct an object using [`Object.fromEntries`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/fromEntries):

```js
let data = {
  Invoice: ["can_view", "can_create", "can_edit", "can_delete"],
  license: ["can_view", "can_create", "can_edit", "can_delete"]
}

function convertdatatoObj(value, group) {
  if (!value && !Array.isArray(value[group]))
    return;

  return Object.fromEntries(
    value[group].map(permission => [permission, { value: permission }])
  )
}

let result = convertdatatoObj(data, "Invoice")

console.log(result)
```

It can be done using [`Array#reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) by cloning the object every time:

```js
let data = {
  Invoice: ["can_view", "can_create", "can_edit", "can_delete"],
  license: ["can_view", "can_create", "can_edit", "can_delete"]
}

function convertdatatoObj(value, group) {
  if (!value && !Array.isArray(value[group]))
    return;

  return value[group]
    .reduce(
      (obj, permission) => ( {...obj, [permission]: { value: permission } } ), 
      {}
    )
}

let result = convertdatatoObj(data, "Invoice")

console.log(result)
```

Or mutating a single instance with [`Object.assign`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign):

```js
let data = {
  Invoice: ["can_view", "can_create", "can_edit", "can_delete"],
  license: ["can_view", "can_create", "can_edit", "can_delete"]
}

function convertdatatoObj(value, group) {
  if (!value && !Array.isArray(value[group]))
    return;

  return value[group]
    .reduce(
      (obj, permission) => Object.assign(obj, { [permission]: { value: permission } } ), 
      {}
    )
}

let result = convertdatatoObj(data, "Invoice")

console.log(result)
```

Comment: can you look this - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61055773/how-to-filtering-array-of-objects-to-another-array-of-objects-in-js

Answer (score 1):

You could take [`Object.fromEntries`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/fromEntries) with a mapped array of entries.

```js
var permissions = ["can_view", "can_create", "can_edit", "can_delete"],
    result = Object.fromEntries(permissions.map(value => [value, { value }]));

console.log(result);
```

Comment: For example , let data = {
  Invoice: ["can_view", "can_create", "can_edit", "can_delete"],
  license: ["can_view", "can_create""] ,
} what would be code format?

Comment: what should be the result of it?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61055773/how-to-filtering-array-of-objects-to-another-array-of-objects-in-js can you look this?