# How to filtering array of objects to another array of objects in js?

Tags: javascript, arrays, function, object, reduce

I have got two arrays of objects. I want to filter data based on permissionObj.

This is coming from database. Here are arrays of sub-arrays in the permissionObj.

I need to do another condition in reduce function . For example , if Pubsidebar value is token is public, I want to keep static content {label: "test",value: "public"} without filtering with permissionObj and if other key and value is match with permissionObj,then it will be push inside token .

```js
let permissionObj = [
  {
    'OA deal': [
      {
        label: 'can view',
        value: 'can_view',
      },
    ],
  },
  {
    Deposit: [
      {
        label: 'can edit',
        value: 'can_edit',
      },
    ],
  },
  {
    Deposit: [
      {
        label: 'can_view',
        value: 'can_view',
      },
    ],
  },

  {
    Journals: [
      {
        label: 'can create',
        value: 'can_create',
      },
    ],
  },
  {
    Dashboard: [
      {
        label: 'can view',
        value: 'can_view',
      },
    ],
  },
  {
    token: [
      {
        label: 'can view',
        value: 'can_create',
      },
    ],
  },
]

const PubSidebar = [
  {
    label: 'Dashboard',
    value: 'can_view',
  },
  {
    label: 'token',
    value: 'public',
    content: [
      {
        key: 'token',
        value: 'can_create',
      },
      {
        key: 'test',
        value: 'public',
      },
    ],
  },
  {
    label: 'OA deal',
    content: [
      {
        label: 'view oadeal',
        key: 'OA deal',
        value: 'can_view',
      },

      {
        label: 'Deposit',
        key: 'Deposit',
        value: 'can_view',
      },
      {
        label: 'Corrections',
        key: 'Corrections',
        value: 'can_edit',
      },
    ],
  },
  {
    label: 'Journals',
    content: [
      {
        label: 'Add Journal',
        key: 'Journals',
        value: 'can_create',
      },
    ],
  },
]

const filterObject = permissionObj.reduce((a, c) => {
  for (const key in c) {
    a[key] = c[key]
  }
  return a
}, {})
const result = PubSidebar.reduce((a, c) => {
  if (
    filterObject[c.label] &&
    c.value &&
    filterObject[c.label].some(s => s.value === c.value)
  ) {
    a.push(c)
  } else if (c.value === 'public' && c.label === 'token') {
    if (
      (c.content = c.content.filter(
        f =>
          filterObject[f.key] &&
          filterObject[f.key].some(s => s.value == f.value)
      ))
    ) {
      c.content = c.content.filter(
        f =>
          filterObject[f.key] &&
          filterObject[f.key].some(s => s.value == f.value)
      )
      a.push(c)
    }
  } else if (c.content.some(s => filterObject[s.key]) && c.content) {
    c.content = c.content.filter(
      f =>
        filterObject[f.key] && filterObject[f.key].some(s => s.value == f.value)
    )
    a.push(c)
  }

  return a
}, [])

console.log(result)
```

Here is code snippet . I am trying to getting public data from sidebar without filtering with permissionObj.

```
my expected output would : 
[
  {
    "label": "Dashboard",
    "value": "can_view"
  },
  {
    "label": "token",
    "value": "public",
    "content": [{
        "key": "test",
        "value": "public"
      }
      {
        "key": "token",
        "value": "can_create"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "label": "OA deal",
    "content": [
      {
        "label": "view oadeal",
        "key": "OA deal",
        "value": "can_view"
      },
      {
        "label": "Deposit",
        "key": "Deposit",
        "value": "can_view"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "label": "Journals",
    "content": [
      {
        "label": "Add Journal",
        "key": "Journals",
        "value": "can_create"
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

Comment: your data and permissions are not stringent, for example ``Journal`` has no `value` and the permission calls it `'Journals'`. btw, how should the nested part be filtered if no permission exists? how do you come to the result with `'Journal'`?

Comment: I just edited my data

Comment: filterObject[c.label] && c.value
        && filterObject[c.label].some(s => s.value == c.value this condition is only 
         for  single object {
                label: "Dashboard",
                value: "can_view"
            },

Comment: else if (c.content.some(s => filterObject[s.key]) && c.content) {
        c.content = c.content.filter(f => filterObject[f.key]
            && filterObject[f.key].some(s => s.value == f.value));
        a.push(c);
    } this condition is only for journals and oa-deals

Comment: can you read my edited code again

Comment: sometimes, we need to run the code and see the output. So it would be good if you create snippet (JSfiddle or anything) then other people can folk it and try to help you.

Comment: I am trying do snippet

Comment: Perfect. try to do it with static data and update your question.

Comment: can you see now my question , I did snippet

Comment: why has permissions now label? is it used anywhere?

Comment: yes , it will be used everywhere , forexample , I want to static data if pubsidebar obj property is public , I don't want to filter with permissionObj

Comment: you can see my question again, I added snippet

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61059100/how-to-filter-array-of-object-and-nested-of-array you can see this .