# How to convert array to object in js?

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, object, functional-programming

I have got list of arrays .

```
let arr = ["one","two"]
```

My trying code is:

```
arr.map(item=>{
  item
})
```

I want to convert array of sub-array

```
[
            {
                "one": [{
                        value: "one"
                    }, 
                ]
            },
            {
                "two": [{
                        value: "two"
                    }, 
                ]
            },
]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try with using [`Object.values()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Object/values).

```js
const arr = ["one", "two"];

const result = Object.values(arr).map(e => {
  return {
    [e]: [{value: e}]
  }
});

console.log(result);
```

Comment: can you look this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61055773/how-to-filtering-array-of-objects-to-another-array-of-objects-in-js

Answer (score 1):

you can also do it like this

```
let arr = ["one","two"]

arr.map(orgValue => {
    [orgValue]: [
      {
        value: orgValue
      }
    ]
  };
);
```

Comment: can you look this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61055773/how-to-filtering-array-of-objects-to-another-array-of-objects-in-js

Answer (score 0):

A simple forEach loop would help

```js
let arr = ["one", "two"];
var res = [];
arr.forEach(val => {
  res.push({
    [val]: [
      {
        value: val
      }
    ]
  });
});
console.log(res);
```